# Inject component into another component

Tags: reactjs

What is the preferred way to inject a component into another component? I have an Object Oriented application structure where a View only knows about its parent View.
Because all my components are 'dynamic' components I do not know the component structure beforehand.

I tried it in two different ways with the following shared code:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var component = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                .. many elements here ..
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var subcomponent = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>test</div>
        );
    }
});

var parentView = React.renderComponent(
    <component>.. subelements</component>,
    document.getElementById('reactContainer')
);
```

**1. Multiple components rendered**

```
var subView = React.renderComponent(
    <subcomponent />,
    parentView.getDOMNode()
);
```

The problem with this is that the super components inner html is replaced by the injected component. Also other errors are popping up. Seems like this is not the React-way of doing this.

**2. Inject subcomponent via setProp with single renderComponent**

Another approach is to set the children prop.

```
parentView.setProps({
    children: <subcomponent />
});
```

This works almost as expected, but also has some drawbacks. It is resetting the children to only the injected component. I could work around this by:

```
parentView.setProps({
    children: [parentView.props.children, <subcomponent />]
});
```

But now the childView is managing the children of its parent. But I could extract this to a method on the parentView.

Another drawback is that when the view-depth is deeper than 2, the reference to the React component is gone because only the rootView is rendered via `React.renderComponent` and thus I can only do setProps on the rootview.

I think I need a `React.renderComponent` for every view, but I don't know a way of how to inject it in the parent.

Comment: I can't fully make sense of your model, but it seems you are fighting the idiomatic react way of doing things. You should perhaps re-read the docs and start again :(
You don't need to inject children and they definitely shouldn't be passed as props. How to handle children is addressed here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html

Comment: I'm also extremely confused by what you're trying to do here.  In order to have a child component inside a parent, you just call the child inside the parent's `render` function.  Why you're trying to insert a child through props is completely beyond me and is absolutely not something you should generally be trying to do with React.

Answer (score 10):

In most cases, the preferred way to pass a component down to another component is using the special *children* prop (like you show in your example):

```
var component = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                .. many elements here ..
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

you can read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)